# The second line I am having trouble understanding the logic of this enumerate function for common prefix

Tags: python-3.x, enumerate

I'd like help in the flow of the program:

```
strings = ["apple", "app", "ape"]

common = next((i for i,(p,*r) in enumerate(zip(*strings)) 
                                 if any(p!=c for c in r)),0)

print(strings[0][:common]) # ap
```

I've asked for the solution of a common prefix program for finding the common prefix in a list of strings. I've received this solution it works and everything but I'm having trouble following the flow of the program from the second line.

Comment: I think it's better to ask for a detailed explanation in the original thread, where this solution is provided to you. However, I tried explaining it below, hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Let's breakdown the line bit by bit:

`zip(*strings)` rearranges the array into an enumerable of the first elements of each elements of the array `strings`, the second ones, the third ones, and so on... until the last element of the shortest element of the array. In this case, it rearranges the array into the enumerable `('a', 'a', 'a'), ('p', 'p', 'p'), ('p', 'p', 'e')`.

`for i,(p,*r) in enumerate(zip(*strings))` enumerates `zip(*strings)` and stores the index of each tuple in variable `i`, the first element of each tuple in variable `p`, and the rest of the elements of each tuple in `r` as  a list. for instance, for the first tuple ('a', 'a', 'a', when enumerated, `i` is `0`, `p` is `"a"`, `r` is `['a', 'a']`.

The `if any(p!=c for c in r)` part filters in any tuple where there is an element `r` that is different to `p`. That is, filters out any tuple where there is a different element.

So, the `(i for i,(p,*r) in enumerate(zip(*strings)) if any(p!=c for c in r))` part shows the indices `i` where the zipped tuple has a different element, that is, the indices `i` at which position any of the strings have different character.

Then put that into `next()` function, and you get the first element of that, which indicates the first index at which any of the strings have a different character.

Now that we get the first index at which any of the strings have a different character, we can conclude that the strings are common before that index.

So then to get the prefix, we take any element of the strings (for the sake of simplicity we take `strings[0]`), then take the substring up until before the different part, so we take from index 0 until before index common, hence `strings[0][:common]`.